# how can I use htmlparser in es5 vanilla js

Tags: javascript, cdn, ecmascript-5

I want to use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser
I search it and I finally find it to cdn https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/htmlparser
Than I import to my es5 vanilla project.

cdns

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/htmlparser@1.7.7/json2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/htmlparser@1.7.7/runtests.min.js"></script>
<script   src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.5/comments/require.js"></script>
```

but I didnt know how call this func

```
    function searchCategoryFunc(){

        const  { parse } =require(['node-html-parser']) ;
        var searchCategory = document.getElementById('searchCategoryInput').value;
        const tempForm = new FormData();
        tempForm.append('searchParameter', searchCategory);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/questionBank/category/view",
            type: "POST",
            serverSide: true,
            data: tempForm,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {

                let parser = new htmlparser
                let parseddata=parser.parse(data)
                document.body.innerHTML = parseddata.querySelector("body")
            },
            error: function(data) {
            toastr["error"]("Category Deleted Failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

this ajax return to me rawHtmlText than I want to parse it for find to body element

I really search but I cannot find thanks for the help.

I search all of internet but I couldnt have nice solution.

Comment: Frame challenge: [A Business Case for Dropping Internet Explorer](https://css-tricks.com/a-business-case-for-dropping-internet-explorer/)

Comment: What led you to choose those URLs to load from CDNs?

Comment: @Quentin I search on internet. and it shows me this

Comment: And what about the results of that search led you to choose those URLs to load from CDNs? Did you perhaps find a complete guide to using that particular NPM module in a browser which you followed? Did you cobble together half a dozen things that looked like they had the right sort of names?

Comment: htmlparser hasn't has a release in 9 years, has 33 recorded issues and 20 open pull requests. It's documentation hasn't been enough for you to get it to run. Are you sure its a good tool to solve your problem with in the first place?

Comment: @Quentin actually, my main parser is https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser with the name of it you see this is a node parser I work on es5 vanilla v8 engine on web